# Looking for non-polynomial functions: with the growth condition: $\phi\big(\theta \frac{s}{t}\big) \leq \frac{\phi(s)}{\phi(t)}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, counterexamples

I am for example(s) of an invertible Convex or concave function $\phi: [0,\infty)\to [0, \infty)$ such that $\phi(0)=0$ and there exists $\theta>0$ and for all $s\leq t$ we have

\begin{align}\label{EqI}\tag{I}
\phi\big(\theta \frac{s}{t}\big)    \leq \frac{\phi(s)}{\phi(t)} \qquad\text{or equaly}  \qquad  \theta  \leq \phi^{-1}\big(\frac{s}{t}\big)\frac{\phi^{-1}(t)}{\phi^{-1}(s)}
\end{align}

The most simple class consists of polynomial functions of the form $\phi(t)= ct^p$ with $c>0$ and $p>0$.

**Question:** Are there other possible non-polynomial examples satisfying $\eqref{EqI}$?

As an attempt with $\phi(t)= e^{t^\alpha}-1$, I wonder if there is a constant $c>0$ such that

$$ \ln(t+1)\ln\left(\frac{s}{t}+1\right)\geq c\ln(s+1),\qquad \text{for all $0\leq s\leq t$}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $f:=\phi$, $u:=s/t$, and $c:=\theta$, the desired inequality can be rewritten as
$$f(cu)f(t)\le f(tu) \tag{1}$$
for $u\in[0,1]$ and real $t\ge0$.

Let us show that (1) holds with $c=1$ if $f(x)\equiv\ln(1+x)$. That is, we have to show that
$$g(t):=\ln(1+u)\ln(1+t)-\ln(1+tu)\le0$$
for $u\in[0,1]$ and real $t\ge0$. We have $g(0)=0$ and
$$g'(t)=\frac{\ln(1+u)}{1+t}-\frac u{1+tu}
\le \frac u{1+t}-\frac u{1+tu}\le0$$
for $u\in[0,1]$ and real $t\ge0$. So, the desired result follows.

---

More generally, any concave function $f$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $0<f'\le1/c$ satisfies (1); here $f'$ denotes the right derivative of $f$. Indeed, then $0\le f(cu)\le u$ for all real $u\ge0$ and hence for
$$h(t):=f(cu)f(t)-f(tu)$$
we have $h(0)=0$ and
$$h'(t)=f(cu)f'(t)-uf'(tu)\le uf'(t)-uf'(tu)\le0$$
for $u\in[0,1]$ and real $t\ge0$.

So, taking any positive decreasing function $f_1$ on $[0,\infty)$ and then letting $c:=1/f_1(0)$ and
$$f(x):=\int_0^x f_1(y)\,dy,$$
for real $x\ge0$, one has (1) satisfied.

---

The inequality
$$ \ln(t+1)\ln\left(\frac{s}{t}+1\right)\ge c\ln(s+1)\qquad \text{for all $0\le s\le t$} \tag{2}$$
in your post does not hold for any real $c>0$ if $s$ is small and $t$ is large, because for such $s$ and $t$ we have $\ln\left(\frac{s}{t}+1\right)\sim\frac{s}{t}$ and $\ln(s+1)\sim s$, whereas $\ln(t+1)/t\to0$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer. can we have an example with a convex function instead of a concave?  In fact, I am working with Young functions "which are convex"... I just forgot to mention it in my question...

Comment: @GuyFsone : I think such convex functions exist. However, that would be a different question -- please ask it in a separate post.

Comment: I will ask not in this room (that won't be serious) but the in stack-exchange: please see here  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4109486

Comment: Or I can just edit the current version and add convex and concave so that you edit yours? See the Edit. please edit your answer. This room is very strict regarding posts..

Comment: @GuyFsone : I don't understand why a post with an additional condition would be less serious than the original one, without the additional condition. Also, I don't think editing one's question to invalidate a valid answer is encouraged on MO.

Comment: The edit does not invalidate your answer.... you may decide to maintain your answer. Read the edit... "Just a subquestion"

Comment: @GuyFsone : I don't think this is a fair edit. Your original question was answered fully. With the latter edit, it looks like the answer is only partial. Anyhow, now your additional question is answered as well at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390723/a-non-polynomial-young-function-satisfying-a-power-like-condition/390724#390724